# Automatically update cells with dependent dropdown values

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have a sheet where there are two columns (Column C and column E). Column E has cells with dropdown menus that are dependent on the value of the cells in the same row, Column C.

I am trying to get the value in Column E to automatically change to the first option of the new corresponding dropdown menu when the value in Column C changes. As it stands, when the value in Column C changes, the value from before in the respective Column E cell remains, and I have to manually click and select from the new list.

Here is what I have to start:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng(1) As Range, rng1 As Range
Set rng(0) = Range("C71:C91")
Set rng(1) = Range("E71:E91")
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, rng(0)) Is Nothing Then
   For Each rng1 In rng(1)
     i = i + 1
     rng1 = Range("" & rng(0).Value2)(i, 1)
   Next
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How are the lists in Col E assigned, and how do they change when the value in Col C is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't fully tested the code, but can see a basic bug. Line:

```
For Each rng1 In rng(1)
```

Should read:

```
For Each rng1 In rng(1).Cells
```

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate the sheet with `Application.CalculateFull` after your if statement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change with Data Validation (Drop-Downs)

- It is assumed that the drop-downs in `E71:E91` 'get' the values from `C71:C91` and that when you change (manually or via VBA) a value in `C71:C91`, the value in the same row of `E71:E91` will be overwritten with this value.
- Out-comment or delete the `Debug.Print` lines when done testing.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Worksheet Change Sequence at " & Now
    Debug.Print "1. '" & Target.Address(0, 0) & "' has changed."

    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Range("C71:C91")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Range("E71:E91")
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    Debug.Print "2. Range references created."
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "3. No intersecting range. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print "3. Intersecting range at '" & irg.Address(0, 0) & "'."
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Debug.Print "4. Error handler activated. Events disabled."
     
    ' Write to intersecting rows only.
    Dim dCol As Long: dCol = drg.Column
    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In irg.Cells
        iCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Value = iCell.Value
    Next iCell
    Debug.Print "5. Written to '" _
        & Intersect(irg.EntireRow, drg).Address(0, 0) & "'."

    'Or:
    ' Write to whole destination range.
    'drg.Value = srg.Value
    'Debug.Print "5. Written to '" & drg.Address(0, 0) & "'."

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Debug.Print "6. Events enabled. Exiting."

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub

' Multi-range example. Best run from 'VBE' with the Immediate window open.
Sub Test()
    Range("C71,C73,C75").Value = "A"
    Range("C73,C75").Value = "B"
    Range("C75").Value = "C"
End Sub
```